# CodeIgniter object controller not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using codeIgniter 3.x. I load a view containing a form that submits to **User.php** controller but whenever I hit the submit button it redirect to this url *"http://localhost/signup/Users/register"* and it always gives "Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server."

following is my **.htaccess** file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /signup/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /signup/index.php
</IfModule>
```

following is autload helper in **autload.php**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');
```

following is **config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/signup/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

following is how I open a form and close it in **Welcome.php** view.

```
<?php echo form_open("Users/register", $attributes);?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Following is **Users.php** controller

```
class Users extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->view('user_registration_view');
}

function index()
{
    $this->register();
}
    function register()
{
    //set validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]|md5');

    //validate form input
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // fails
        $this->load->view('user_registration_view');
    }
    else
    {
        //insert the user registration details into database
        $data = array(
            'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
            'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );

        // insert form data into database
        if ($this->user_model->insertUser($data))
        {
            // send email
            if ($this->user_model->sendEmail($this->input->post('email')))
            {
                // successfully sent mail
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully Registered! Please confirm the mail sent to your Email-ID!!!</div>');
                redirect('user/register');
            }
            else
            {
                // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                redirect('user/register');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
            redirect('user/register');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your `user.php` controller file.

Comment: @urfusion done.

Comment: first place `die('here');` in your  `__construct` to check the call.

Comment: @urfusion nothing is printed.

Comment: try with this htaccess `RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: @urfusion hey listen it worked when i added index.php to the url inthe address bar.

Comment: cool, You can remove that index.php too by htaccess.

Comment: @urfusion I extremely appreciate your help and I would be extremely grateful if you can show me how to remove that index.php from .htaccess.

Comment: I have added answer, check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is under your signup folder ( as it appears by your .htaccess file ) then you need to do the following...

**.htaccess**
This lives in the same folder as your application. i.e the same folder as the system index.php file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

As your URL is http://localhost/signup/ which you have set correctly in your $config['base_url'] that should work.

I just created a dummy test site and tested it.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: It works! The problem was that.htaccess was inside the application folder.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `htaccess` so change it to default

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And in config

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]), "", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
$config["base_url"] = $root;
```

Comment: it works now, thanks! I also changed the location  of .htaccess. what does the code in config do ?

Answer (score 0):

Filename should be same as class name **Users.php** `Class Users extends CI_Controller`

Comment: `<?php echo form_open("User/register", $attributes);?>` should be `users/register`

Comment: done and still not working. I will edit the post now. @Riyenz

Answer (score 0):

I think you made mistake while redirecting ...

replace :
 redirect('user/register');

with :
redirect('Users/register'); OR redirect('Users/register','refresh');

Comment: The main problem was having my .htaccess file inside my application folder.